# How to publish master page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, master-page, publishing

I have to update the master page of sharepoint online. I followed the below steps. 
But the changes made are not reflected on site pages and are only visible on the site settings and site contents.

1. copied the Seattle renamed it.
2. added the javascript and CSS.
3. set it as default master page.
4. saved the master page.

I don't know how to publish it can anyone advise. I don't see a button to publish as when you see in a workflow. I am working on sharepoint online

Comment: For publishing master page are you using [SharePoint Designer](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/056830ed-cb9a-4e74-a49c-5273a7eacf1e/master-page-created-in-sharepoint-designer-does-not-appear-in-look-and-feel-master-page?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious) or [Designer Manager](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn794224.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To publish the master page, you could go to site settings in the browser->Master pages and page layouts->select the master page you have edited->click the item menu->click the publish a major version.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you go to `Site Settings : Site Master Page Settings` then check whether  you have selected Site master page and system master page as your own Seattle master page or not.

If you want to publish the master page, then you have to open the online site in SP designer and publish the master page resides under `_catalog` folder.